# Syntax error whenever I execute this code

Tags: linux, bash

Whenever I execute this code I get the error syntax error near `else`.

Here is the code:

```
if [ -z $loc ] then
     if [uname -a| grep 64 >/dev/null] then
        sdir=$KALDI_ROOT/tools/srilm/bin/i686-m64
else
            sdir=$KALDI_ROOT/tools/srilm/bin/i686
      fi
      if [ -f $sdir/ngram-count ] then
            echo "Using SRILM language modelling tool from $sdir"
            export PATH=$PATH:$sdir
      else
            echo "SRILM toolkit is probably not installed.
              Instructions: tools/install_srilm.sh"
            exit 1
      fi
fi
```

Comment: Superuser isn't a script-checking service. What have you tried and where are you getting stuck?

Comment: if [ -z $loc ]; then
     if uname -a | grep 64 >/dev/null; then
        sdir=$KALDI_ROOT/tools/srilm/bin/i686-m64 
    else
            sdir=$KALDI_ROOT/tools/srilm/bin/i686
      fi
      if [ -f $sdir/ngram-count ]; then
            echo "Using SRILM language modelling tool from $sdir"
            export PATH=$PATH:$sdir
      else
            echo "SRILM toolkit is probably not installed.
              Instructions: tools/install_srilm.sh"
            exit 1
      fi
fithis is the code i jst need to know syntax error

Comment: I've seen the code, you posted it in your question. Where does the syntax error occur?

Answer (score 2):

#### I get the error syntax error near `else`

You can use http://www.shellcheck.net/ to check your syntax:

```
$ shellcheck myscript

Line 1:
if [ -z $loc ] then
               ^-- SC1010: Use semicolon or linefeed before 'then' (or quote to make it literal).

Line 2:
     if [uname -a| grep 64 >/dev/null] then
     ^-- SC1009: The mentioned parser error was in this if expression.
        ^-- SC1073: Couldn't parse this test expression.
         ^-- SC1035: You need a space after the [ and before the ].
         ^-- SC1009: Use 'if cmd; then ..' to check exit code, or 'if [[ $(cmd) == .. ]]' to check output.
                 ^-- SC1035: You are missing a required space here.
                 ^-- SC1072: Fix any mentioned problems and try again.

$
```

Fixing the obvious errors (missing `;`s and spaces gives:

```
if [ -z $loc ]; then
     if [ uname -a | grep 64 >/dev/null ] then
        sdir=$KALDI_ROOT/tools/srilm/bin/i686-m64
else
            sdir=$KALDI_ROOT/tools/srilm/bin/i686
      fi
      if [ -f $sdir/ngram-count ]; then
            echo "Using SRILM language modelling tool from $sdir"
            export PATH=$PATH:$sdir
      else
            echo "SRILM toolkit is probably not installed.
              Instructions: tools/install_srilm.sh"
            exit 1
      fi
fi
```

And:

```
$ shellcheck myscript

Line 2:
     if [ uname -a | grep 64 >/dev/null ]; then
     ^-- SC1009: The mentioned parser error was in this if expression.
        ^-- SC1073: Couldn't parse this test expression.
          ^-- SC1009: Use 'if cmd; then ..' to check exit code, or 'if [[ $(cmd) == .. ]]' to check output.
                   ^-- SC1072: Fix any mentioned problems and try again.

$
```

You can fix the remaining errors yourself.

---

#### ShellCheck - A shell script static analysis tool

> ShellCheck is a GPLv3 tool that gives warnings and suggestions for
>   bash/sh shell scripts:
>
> Screenshot of a terminal showing problematic shell script lines
>   highlighted.
>
> [image]
>
> The goals of ShellCheck are
>
> - To point out and clarify typical beginner's syntax issues that cause a shell to give cryptic error messages.
> - To point out and clarify typical intermediate level semantic problems that cause a shell to behave strangely and
>     counter-intuitively.
> - To point out subtle caveats, corner cases and pitfalls that may cause an advanced user's otherwise working script to fail under future
>     circumstances.

Source [ShellCheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/blob/master/README.md)